# Salesforce Inbox Application under GDPR Compliance

Tags: salesforce1-app, gdpr

The Salesforce Application "Salesforce Inbox" comes with a feature where the user can track their Customer's data like Customer's receiving location, IP Address etc.

My Concern is, this could be against the GDPR compliance as the Customer didn't explicitly gave consent to be tracked. Is there any way to know whether this comes under GDPR compliance or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Salesforce Spring '18 Release Notes -

> Prevent users from getting read receipts for email messages they send. Read receipts include information such as when the recipient opens the message and from where. Laws and regulations can require you to honor and respect your customers’ wishes regarding the personal data you collect.
>
> Here are a couple laws that are important to many companies collecting and processing their customers’ data:
>
> General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), European Union
> Gramm-Leach-Bliley Act (GLB Act), United States
>
> To prevent users from getting read receipts, from Setup, enter Inbox in the Quick Find box, then select **Setup Assistant**. Toggle the Send Read Receipts setting to **Disabled**.

This means the Salesforce Inbox tracking feature may be against the GDPR compliance which could be turned off by using the above method.

For more visit this link - [Prevent Read Receipts to Enhance Privacy](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_sales_einstein_eac_read_receipts.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no legal genius and don't take this as legally accurate, but under GDPR there is a provision for 'legitimate interest' and also that location information doesn't necessarily mean it's personal data. But legitimate interest is that you have a provision to process personal data before they have agreed to process it "in ways they would reasonably expect and which have a minimal privacy impact, or where there is a compelling justification for the processing". ICO has a page about legitimate interest: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/lawful-basis-for-processing/legitimate-interests/. Inbox may fit here? Maybe not? But Salesforce has a huge team working on GDPR and have already started releasing features to support GDPR.

Comment: I just found an official documentation telling that Inbox email tracking could be against the GDPR and they provided an option how to disable it. Will put my answer down ASAP